# Laravel 9 retorna 204 para algumas rotas especificas sem chegar ao controller

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

essa é minha primeira pergunta então desculpem se algo sair do padrão.

Tenho uma API em Laravel 9 + Sanctum, e recentemente apareceu um problema extremamente estranho. Alguns dias atras, conseguia bater tranquilamente na rota GET: /admin/products/categories, porém, de uma hora pra outra (com a api inalterada por dias), essa rota começou a dar 204.

**api.php**

```php
// ...
Route::prefix('/products')->name('products.')->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'is_admin'])->group(function () {
    // ...
    Route::prefix('/categories')->name('categories.')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', [ProductCategoriesController::class, 'list'])->name('list');
    });
});
```

A primeira coisa que pensei foi que talvez fosse cache, então limpei o cache das rotas, dos eventos, da config e do cache em si. Nenhuma alteração.

Coloquei um die na primeira linha da action dessa rota, e o estranho é que nunca chegou a entrar na action. Logo pensei que talvez fosse algo com o path da rota ter travado algo. Troquei de /categories, para /categories-2, e o resultado foi: se a request for para a rota /categories-2, retorna 204, e se a request for feita na rota antiga (agora inexistente em tese), continua retornando 204. Mesmo se a action informada (ou até o controller) não existir, da 204. Se eu mudar o path/name da rota continua como 204, mesmo que devesse estourar 404.

Comment: E as rotas dentro do prefixo `/products`, estão funcionando normalmente (`/products/1` por exemplo)?

Answer (score -4):

se você tiver uma rota com uma variavel ela sempre vai entrar nela. Por exemplo:

```
...
Route::get('/products/{id}', [...])->name('rota1');
...
Route::prefix('/products')->name('products.')->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'is_admin'])->group(function () {
  ...
  Route::prefix('/categories')->name('categories.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [ProductCategoriesController::class, 'list'])->name('list');
  });
});
```

Ele sempre vai entrar na **rota1** nesse caso você deve adicionar a rota com a variavel sempre por último para que entre nela apenas se não tiver nenhuma outra rota com o mesmo nome dessa forma:

```
...
Route::prefix('/products')->name('products.')->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'is_admin'])->group(function () {
  ...
  Route::prefix('/categories')->name('categories.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [ProductCategoriesController::class, 'list'])->name('list');
  });
});
...
Route::get('/products/{id}', [...])->name('rota1');
...
```

Assim ele vai priorizar a rota com o nome fixo e não com a variavel.